# Extract package name and comments from package files

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to get the package name and first lines of comments from a PL/SQL package file (specification and / or body) or from the package compiled in the BD.

I know that exists a script to get package name, but it needed get description from the package.

For example, if I need to get the package names, I can execute this select:

```
select * from all_objects where object_name like 'pack%';
```

But if I need to get in the query result plus the package name, the first lines from package. If the package starts with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_test AS
/* **************************************************** */
*  Description: maintenance package from suppliers table *
*  Author:  reymagnus                                    *
*  Creation date: 09/04/2019                             *
*  (another comments)                                    *
*  **************************************************** */
```

I expect to get this:

```
Object_Type   Object_Name  Description
===========   ===========  ===========   
PACKAGE       pack_test    maintenance package from suppliers table
```

Or

```
Object_Type   Object_Name  Description_line
===========   ===========  ================ 
PACKAGE       pack_test    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_test AS
PACKAGE       pack_test    /* **************************************************** */
PACKAGE       pack_test    *  Description: maintenance package from suppliers table *
```

Maybe I need to join the all_objects and all_source table and get only <= 3 lines.

Comment: Maybe you do (looks like a good idea). Did you try it?

Comment: Regarding author and date,  I think stuff like that shouldn't be in the package header. After all, after a while there will be modifications, and you'll have multiple authors and multiple dates. Instead store your changes in version control, so you have author+date+commit message/change description for each change you make to the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get the package name from `all_objects`, because it's there anyway.

Parsing the comment should be doable. Just look for a line that starts with `*   Description:` and take the rest of that line.

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` could be a good function to parse that, or some basic string functions like so:

```
select
  o.OWNER,
  o.OBJECT_NAME,
  ( select
      MIN(TRIM(SUBSTR(s.TEXT, INSTR(s.TEXT, 'Description:') + 12)))
    from 
      ALL_SOURCE s 
    where
      s.NAME = o.OBJECT_NAME
      and s.OWNER = o.OWNER
      and s.LINE <= 5
      and s.TEXT like '% Description:%') as DESCRIPTION
from
  ALL_OBJECTS o
where
  o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE';
```

It must be noted that this check is a bit crude. Theoretically the text `Description:` could also be part of some code or query, so you could theoretically get a false positive and get a weird description.

In addition, this check is quite strict. If you typed `description` (lowercase), or `description :` (space before colon) or `*Description:` (no space between the asterisk and the word), there won't be a match.

Also, I used `MIN` to get *any* of the descriptions in case there is more than one. Personally I think it's fine to catch edge cases like that. You could also use `LIST_AGG` to return all of them, which has the nice benefit of allowing multi-line descriptions... :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create a logging table

```
create table t_log( obj_name varchar2(35), obj_type varchar2(35), obj_rows varchar2(4000) );
```

and populate by using `user_source` dictionary view and restricting to three lines

```
declare
  v_plsql_unit varchar2(35):= 'my_package';
begin
  for c in ( select * from user_source s where s.name = upper(v_plsql_unit) order by s.line )
  loop
   begin 
      insert into t_log values( c.name, c.type, c.text );
    exit when c.line = 3;
   end;  
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

the descriptions of package spec and package body are mostly after '/*' or '--' symbols, and there is no criteria that description keyword must be there, unless it is a business criteria. if that is the criteria, then keyword can be used, else the below query can be referred and altered as per need.

```
-- package to query: sample_pkg
select o.owner, 
       o.object_name,
      (select listagg(a.text ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.line asc)  
       from all_source a 
       where a.name =o.object_name
         and a.line between (select b.line from all_source b where b.name=a.name and b.text like '%'||chr(47)||'*%')
                        and (select c.line from all_source c where c.name =a.name and c.text like '%*'||chr(47)||'%')
            ) description
from all_objects o 
where o.object_type like 'PACK%' 
and o.object_name like 'SAMP%';

-- output
OWNER       OBJECT_NAME DESCRIPTION
SQL_user    SAMPLE_PKG  /* 
                        sample spec description 
                        */
```